# unable to deploy react app to github pages 404 error

Tags: reactjs, github, deployment, package.json

I'm currently trying to deploy my react app to either Netlify or GitHub Pages, but I'm receiving a 404 error or not loading the app. Everything runs fine on my local host. I'm not too sure if this is the problem, but I think I'm not properly calling my app or root from the index.html. Also I'm not sure if this is the problem.

Here is my github page (doesn't run the app): https://mattfang1999.github.io/matt-task-manager-app/
Here is the netlify (404 error): https://condescending-galileo-fe4225.netlify.app/

Currently, here is my index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <link rel="icon" href="http://example.com/favicon.png">


    
  <title>Matt's Task Manager</title>
</head>

<body>
  <noscript>
    You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.
  </noscript>
  <div id="root"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

And here is my index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import  {App}  from './App';
import './App.scss';


render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Finally, here is my App.js

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import { Header } from './components/layout/Header';
import { Content } from './components/layout/Content';

import { ProjectsProvider, SelectedProjectProvider} from './context';




export const App = ({ darkModeDefault = false }) => {
  const [darkMode, setDarkMode] = useState(darkModeDefault);
  return (
    <SelectedProjectProvider>
      <ProjectsProvider>
        <main
          data-testid="application"
          className={darkMode ? 'darkmode' : undefined}
        >
          <Header darkMode={darkMode} setDarkMode={setDarkMode} />
          <Content />
        </main>
      </ProjectsProvider>
    </SelectedProjectProvider>
  );
};
```

Here is my package.json

```
{
  "homepage": "https://mattfang1999.github.io/matt-task-manager-app/",
  "name": "taskmanagerapp",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.1.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.1.10",
    "firebase": "^6.2.4",
    "gh-pages": "^3.1.0",
    "install": "^0.13.0",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.12.8",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "react-icons": "^3.11.0",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.0",
    "web-vitals": "^0.2.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "predeploy": "npm run build",
"deploy": "gh-pages -d build",
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What's weird is that your links look like this: `/mattfang1999/matt-task-manager-app.git/static/css/` and they should look like this: `/matt-task-manager-app/static/css/`

Comment: I think I'm unsure which homepage link I have to put in my package.json

Answer (score 0):

I've cloned your repo and could successfully deploy it to [GitHub Pages](https://zsoltime.github.io/ngirews/) when I moved the content of the `taskmanagerapp` folder up one level and run `npm run deploy` in the root folder (where the `package.json` file is).

*Update:* I've also tried to deploy it without changing anything apart from changing the `homepage` URL in the `package.json` file and it's been also [deployed fine](https://zsoltime.github.io/pospof/).

*Update 2:* If my repo's URL is `https://github.com/zsoltime/pospof`, I set my homepage in package.json to  `"homepage": "https://zsoltime.github.io/pospof/"`.

Comment: What would be considered the root folder?

Comment: For changing the homepage, did you just use the HTTPS link github provides, or the website recommended from the setting? And for the first solution, what would be considered the root folder? Zsolt Meszaros